# Abrir una nueva ventana

Tags: html

Se que para abrir un link en `html` se usa,`<a href="algo..">link</a>` y para abrir otra pagina se usa `<a href="algo.." target="_blank">link</a>` pero no se como puedo hacer para que al hacer click en el link me muestre lo que necesito pero en una venta externa del navegador...espero haberme hecho entender y agradecería que me colaboraran con sus conocimientos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es un simple ejemplo de lo que trato de hace...aqui al oprimir en el boton resultado del cuetionario me muestra esa ventana.

 
Este es mi codigo.

```
$("#ver").click(function(event) {
    var id = 40;
    window.open('../../load_students/' + id, '_blank');

});
```

Comment: es decir, quieres otra instancia del navegador en lugar de una pestaña más, correcto?

Comment: exactamente....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solo con HTML creo que no es posible hacerlo, pero si se puede acercar a lo que buscas con un poco de Javascript, aquí te lo dejo.

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('https://www.google.es','','toolbar=yes');void 0">Nueva Instancia</a>
```

Comment: sabes alguna forma de hacerlo pero dentro del javascript?..con este codigo......$("#ver").click(function(event) {
    var id = 40;
    window.open('../../load_students/' + id, '_blank');

});

Comment: @Daniel, primero deberías colocarle el atributo `ID` a tu elemento HTML, puedes editar tu código basado en la respuesta del usuario Cifu.

Comment: @Mauricio si estas en lo correcto, el problema es que esa gestion de hacer la ventana externa la estoy manejando directamente con el javascript es decir que ese ID lo estoy tomando de una funcion que esta dentro del JS y se la paso a la funcion que me va a mandar el dato y me lo va a mostrar en la venta externa. Espero que me entiendas.

Comment: Lo que quiere decir Mauricio es que en el HTML basta con que pongas <a id="ver" href="" target="_blank">link</a> y ya estarás haciendo referencia al $("#ver").. de JQuery (Javascript).

Comment: bueno ahí en ese caso no me funciona porque yo igual estoy tomando el id de un botón que esta dentro de una función en el JS.

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript: abrirNuevaVentana('parametrosSiEsQueLosNecesitas')" >
   Click para nueva ventana 
</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function abrirNuevaVentana(parametros) {
        var url = 'http://midominio.com/consultar?';
        url += 'variable=' + parametros;

        var nuevaVentana = (window.open(url, 'TituloParaLaNuevaVentana'));
        if (nuevaVentana ) {
            nuevaVentana .focus();
        }
    }
```

Referencia: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

La MDN será tu nueva biblia si decides aprender desarrollo web, aquí te dejo otro enlace para que puedas expandirte: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/index.htm

Comment: voy a editar la pregunta para que captes mas la idea, he cometido el error de no hacerme entender muy bien....he probado tu codigo y es funcional pero me esta trabajando de la misma forma a como lo tengo.